# What are i-vectors and x-vectors in the context of Speech Recognition?

Tags: speech-processing, speech-recognition, speech

I have read that **i-vectors** and **x-vectors** are widely used in speaker recognition tasks but I don't get the difference between them and how exactly they work. Can someone explain it starting from the ground to a bit technical?
I came across following papers talking about these terms:
https://www.danielpovey.com/files/2018_icassp_xvectors.pdf
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00514.pdf
https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2846832

Answer (score 9):

The i-vectors and x-vectors share the ability to represent speech utterance in a compact way (as a vector of fixed size, regardless of length of the utterance).

The extraction algorithms of i-vectors and x-vector are quite different. The x-vector concept is newer and the name of the method is similar to "i-vector" to suggests that this representation can be used instead of i-vectors in state-of-the-art speaker (or language) recognition systems.

There are many good sources explaining how i-vectors work, I recommend [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/sshum/talks/ivector_tutorial_interspeech_27Aug2011.pdf) presentation from Najim Dehak (who is the inventor of the i-vector concept).

The x-vectors are embeddings extracted with DNN, but more detailed explanation can be found [here](http://danielpovey.com/files/2017_interspeech_embeddings.pdf) (there is also a [youtube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwSVs7muapQ) explaining the concepts presented in this paper).